# Python list value gets overwritten, why?

Tags: python, django

I have a **recipients query** containing two recipients with the **ID 1 and 2**: 
I loop over each one to build json output:

```
    data = []
    this_tem = {}

    for item in recipients:
        this_tem['recipient_id'] = item.pk
        data.append(this_tem)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

This gives me:

```
[
    {
        "recipient_id": 2,
    },
    {
        "recipient_id": 2,
    }
]
```

As you can see it should be `recipient_id 1` and `recipient_id 2` however, my loop overwrites the value, why?

Comment: change to data.append( {'recepient_id': item.pk } ).. no need for this_tem.. or define this_tem inside the loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this_tem` is a reference to a single object (a dict) which you repeatedly modify and append in your loop. You overwrite the value of that key in the loop.

You need to create a new dict each iteration:

```
data = []

for item in recipients:
    this_tem = {}
    this_tem['recipient_id'] = item.pk
    data.append(this_tem)
```

**Edit**
As Grijesh Chauhan graciously pointed out, the expression and loop can be simplified vis a vie a list comprehension:

```
data = [{'recipient_id': item.pk} for item in recipients]
```

Comment: or just `data.append({'recipient_id': item.pk})` or use LC

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, why not both!? ^_^

Answer (score 3):

You're appending a dictionary, which is a mutable object.

So after your loop, `data` contains two references to the same dictionary.
You'll have to append new dictionaries in each iteration, e.g. like this:

```
for item in recipients:
    data.append(dict(recipient_id = item.pk))
```

Comment: which is better dict( or data.append(this_tem)?

Comment: With the current dict (having only one key), i prefer the `append(dict(..))` version - simply because it avoids the need for another variable and saves one or two lines of code. But it's basically a matter of taste I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

This is because this_tem is declared outside for loop

```
data = []
for item in recipients:
    this_tem = {}
    this_tem['recipient_id'] = item.pk
    data.append(this_tem)

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Declaring outside is not the actual reason why this happens. Please check the other answers.

Comment: when declaring this_tem outside the loop, it is being modified and append in the loop