# How to store inputs under a vairible

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to do a project, here is the task,Your program is for a shop.
The shop wants to know how many books are being bought by a customer (input an integer)
For each book, the shopkeeper needs to enter the book name
The program should then produce a list of all the books being bought by that customer

Here is what I got so far, my program asks the same question the amount of times the user inputs but only stores the last answer the user input so when I want it to print it prints the last input, pls help

```
    x = int(input("How many books do you have? "))
    for i in range(x):
      var = input("What the name of one of the book(s)")
      print(var)
```

Comment: you will probably want to append the input to a list of books

Comment: one variable can store only one data. To store multiple data, you need to use a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list value gets overwritten, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702528/python-list-value-gets-overwritten-why)

Answer (score 0):

Do that in any language, previous values of `var` will be overwritten by the current iteration.

Pythonic fix: just do it in a list comprehension:

```
var = [input("What the name of one of the book(s)") for _ in range(x)]
```

you'll get a `list` of book names.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
x =int(input("How many books do you have? "))
#print(type(x))
list1=[]
for i in range(x):
    var = raw_input("What the name of one of the book(s):")
    #print type(var)
    list1.append(var)
print list1
```

even if u didn't mention like this:

```
x = int(input("How many books do you have? "))
```

it will give integer.try this:

```
x = input("How many books do you have? ")
```